# How different is a mantra from a prayer?

Tags: gods, mantras, prayer

Whenever we try to think of God, mantra, prayer etc are the things which come to our mind.

- I was trying to understand how is a mantra different than a normal prayer ?
- If we consider a mantra it is also a form of prayer, then what is the speciality of a mantra ?
- And , which is more effective in terms of communicating with the divine god ?

Comment: In mantra japa responsibility lies with the reciter.  The results of such recitation, whether good or bad (due to wrong way of recitation) will be fast and  accrue to the reciter.  In prayer or nAma japa, the responsibility lies with the God to goad the reciter in the proper way

Comment: A prayer is informal in nature but mantra is technical and formal. Mantra japa has lots of rules and prerequisites associated but not so for prayers. This is the difference but finding a suitable scriptural reference seems to be a hard thing for me otherwise I would have written an answer